# Often aborted connections to db (MariaDB)

Tags: database-connection, c3p0, mariadb-10.5

I have a Windows server running a MySQL server. There are two databases for different applications on the MySQL server.

In total, around 25 users access the database server every day.

The database server is not in the user's local network (sometimes not even in the same country).

Unfortunately, we often have problems with users not being able to connect to the server despite a stable internet connection. Only after several attempts does the user manage to connect.

When I look in the log files on the database server, I see a lot of entries like this:

**1. 2024-03-19 14:08:42 2378 [Warning] Aborted connection 2378 to db: 'CMS_DB' user: 'JOHN' host: 'bba-83-130-102-145.alshamil.net.ae' ( Got an error reading communication packets)**

**2. 2024-03-19 13:44:45 1803 [Warning] Aborted connection 1803 to db: 'CMS_DB' user: 'REMA' host: '188.137.160.92' (Got timeout reading communication packets)**

**3. 2024-03-19 11:51:08 1526 [Warning] Aborted connection 1526 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '92.216.164.102' (Got an error reading packet communications)**

**4. 2024-03-19 11:51:08 1526 [Warning] Aborted connection 1526 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '92.216.164.102' (This connection closed normally without authentication)**

**5. 2024-03-19 11:55:26 1545 [Warning] IP address '94.202.229.78' could not be resolved: No such host is known.**

My my.ini file looks like this:

```
[mysqld]
datadir = C:/Program Files/MariaDB 10.5/data
port = 3306
max_allowed_packet=1024M
net_read_timeout=3600
net_write_timeout=3600

# The maximum amount of concurrent sessions the MySQL server will
# allow. One of these connections will be reserved for a user with
# SUPER privileges to allow the administrator to login even if the
# connection limit has been reached.
max_connections = 600

wait_timeout = 3600
interactive_timeout = 3600

# The default character set that will be used when a new schema or table is
# created and no character set is defined
character-set-server = utf8

# Query cache is used to cache SELECT results and later return them
# without actual executing the same query once again. Having the query
# cache enabled may result in significant speed improvements, if your
# have a lot of identical queries and rarely changing tables. See the
# "Qcache_lowmem_prunes" status variable to check if the current value
# is high enough for your load.
# Note: In case your tables change very often or if your queries are
# textually different every time, the query cache may result in a
# slowdown instead of a performance improvement.
query_cache_size=50M

# Maximum size for internal (in-memory) temporary tables. If a table
# grows larger than this value, it is automatically converted to disk
# based table This limitation is for a single table. There can be many
# of them.
tmp_table_size=256M

slow_query_log = ON
slow_query_log_file = C:/Program Files/MariaDB 10.5/data/slow_query_log.log
general_log = ON
general_log_file = C:/Program Files/MariaDB 10.5/data/general_log.log
log_error = C:/Program Files/MariaDB 10.5/data/error_log.log

innodb_page_size = 65536
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4085M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 32M
innodb_log_file_size = 2047M


[client]
port = 3306
plugin-dir = C:/Program Files/MariaDB 10.5/lib/plugin
```

My c3p0 settings in the hibernate.cfg.xml looks like this:

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">7</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">120</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">20</property>
```

It was difficult for me to see through all the settings.

I want users to be able to connect to the database server easily without annoying me every time :D

What could be the problem? Do my settings match? Can someone who knows about this help me?

I am very grateful for any helpful answer, as I have been struggling with this for almost 5 weeks, but to no avail. Thanks in advance

If I should post any other settings like server variables, let me know.

Additional information

- OS Version --> Microsoft Windows Server 2022 Standard (version
  10.0.20348)
- RAM --> 32 GB
- CPU --> Intel(R) Xeon(R) E-2314 CPU @ 2.80GHz 4 Cores
- Disk --> 1 TB SSD

Link of the my.ini file : https://jpst.it/3DRYr

I should also note that last night around 9:00 p.m. One user was no longer able to connect at all.
I simply restarted the Windows server and after that it worked. After the restart, no users complained about connection problems (yet).

Comment: Are the users connecting to- mariadb directly remotely? If so, that may be the cause of the issue as mariadb connections require stable network. You need to do some debugging to determine if the root cause is programming related (question is for SO), or network related (question should be moved to serverfault sister site) or database configuration issue (question should be move to DBA site).

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

for server workload tuning analysis to provide CONNECT smoothing suggestions.

Comment: Hi! I don't have any great insight into what's going on, but a c3p0 suggestion would be to add `<property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>`. Your application will be less likely to experience stale or broken Connections. For more on Connection testing, see https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing

Comment: @Shadow Many thanks for your response. 
Yes, currently users still access the database directly remotely. Only later did I realize that that wasn't a good idea. But unfortunately only after I have programmed everything.

Nevertheless, I have prepared a Java server that will serve as a communication layer between the database and the clients.

However, I still have to change a few things before I can put it into operation. For me it's a question of time at the moment.

Comment: @WilsonHauck 

A) Result of SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables -> 292;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME -> Will follow later because I restarted the Windows server 12 hours ago.
C) Result of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES -> https://jpst.it/3DRZm
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST -> https://jpst.it/3DVIl
E) STATUS; not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS; -> I became a syntax error while executing just "STATUS"
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; -> https://jpst.it/3DVNh

Comment: Zaki,  Thanks for data posted.  It looks like Show Full Processlist is just page 1 of how many pages?  Looking forward to your SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after 24 hours to allow workload analysis.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Show Yes, the full processlist is just one page.
Here is now the result of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS after more than 24 hours server uptime -> https://jpst.it/3E0ct

Comment: @Zaki Thanks, Wordload Analysis in process.  Suggestions may be delayed a day or two due to medical appointments.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I have to thank. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your my.ini [mysqld] section.

Zaki,

General Log is normally NOT ON.

Until actually needed and will be used,

general_log=OFF

When needed from MySQL Command Prompt,

SET GLOBAL general_log=ON

then when you have sufficient logging completed, usually less than one minute - unless you have a VERY LONG executing process,

SET GLOBAL general_log=OFF

to avoid filling your storage with information you will NEVER look at.
Trust me a full storage device is NO FUN to deal with.

Do you have a REAL good reason for setting innodb_page_size anything
other than the default of 16384?

Consider editing your my.cnf to get back to the default from 64K
This has helped the few instances where they have attempted anything
other than 16384 and been troubled with incidents out of nowhere.

Additional suggestions will be provided after posting the additional information requested in a comment above.

Comment: Thanks for posting your my.ini content.  Could you post the Additional information requested 2024 03 19 by me?

Comment: Thank you also for your answer. I have added the requested information to my question. I'm still in the process of gathering the rest of the information.

Comment: I just updated my post and left a comment with the information requests in response to your comment above.
Please let me know if it was what you wanted to see.
Thanks !

Comment: @Zaki Could you share the link to your data from SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after 24 hours.  The other data posted a few hours earlier is good to work with.

Comment: @Zaki  You really NEED TO from MySQL Command Prompt, SET GLOBAL general_log=0;   for OFF to avoid filling your storage device and allow MySQL to complete more useful work.  Unless you are somehow using the General Log details.

Comment: I needed general_log back then to analyze specific queries. But now I don't need it anymore and will deactivate it too. Thanks for the tip! Hoping it's better.
Since the last server restart, no user has contacted me about connection problems.
But that definitely can't be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.ini [mysqld] section

```
innodb_page_size=16384  # from 65536 for the default 
thread_pool_size=3  # from 4 you only have 4 CPU's and need 1 free
innodb_io_capacity=500  # from 200 to use more of the available SSD IOPS
read_rnd_buffer_size=16384  # from 262144 to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 237
```

There are many more opportunities to improve performance.  View my profile.

Observations:
com_rollback reported 9,229 in 1.6 days of uptime.  Rollbacks need to be investigated and prevented, if possible. General Log Analysis may be required.
For replication durability, binlog_format is usually ROW, not MIXED.
innodb_secondary_index_triggered_cluster_reads reported 25,512,913 (RPS of 183) and is usually caused by tables with NO Primary Key.  For a query to find your tables with No Primary Key, provide an email address, please.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your suggestion. I'll install it this evening and restart the MariaDB server.

Unfortunately there were a lot of connection problems today.
This time there were many more aborted clients than last time, today the value was 648 after 25 hours of server runtime. :(
The last extract of the status from March 21, 2024 was after 42 hours of server running time and therefore only 485 canceled clients.

Here is the last status excerpt from today after 25 hours of server running time:
https://jpst.it/3El0Q

Comment: I was just examining a client's log file and saw that the following warnings or errors were thrown before the client lost connection:

1. Warning: https://jpst.it/3El7o 

2. Warning: WARN  BasicResourcePool:220 - Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@6f105a72 is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.

3. Error: ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:142 - Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!

Does it mean anything to you?

Comment: When setting the values you suggested in the my.ini file, the following errors occurred:
2024-03-26  6:59:25 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Data file '.\ibdata1' uses page size 65536, but the innodb_page_size start-up parameter is 16384
2024-03-26  6:59:25 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Corrupted page [page id: space=0, page number=0] of datafile '.\ibdata1' could not be found in the doublewrite buffer.
2024-03-26  6:59:25 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error

Comment: @Zaki I would put the innodb_page_size back to 65536.  Until you can research requirements to get back to the default.  Please view my profile and get in touch.

Comment: I wrote you an email today at wlhauck@aol.com to get more suggestions for my database configuration.